# In French, how do you say "If it isn't X, then what is?"

Tags: expressions, anglais

You use this English expression to emphasise that something you are talking about has all the characteristics you associate with X. I'm not sure if the following works:

> Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure, alors qu'est-ce que c'est ?

Also, can I omit the main clause and say:

> Si ce n'est pas ce qu'on appelle passer un sale quart d'heure !
>
> Si ce n'est pas ce qu'on appelle passer un sale quart d'heure, ça !

Comment: These are all good.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. When you drop the main clause, do you need to include the part "ce qu'on appelle"? I mean, can you say: "Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure !" or "Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure, ça !"

Comment: I think this is basically a rhetorical question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). All is correct including your last comment. You can also say "Si *ça* ce n'est pas... " (the tone should insist on "ça"). The positive/inverted form can be used too: "si ça c'est un bon match, alors qu'est-ce qu'un mauvais match ?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: nearly all is said in the comments following your question (and at first by [@StéphaneGimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%C3%A9phane-gimenez)).

First, all the proposed variations (including in comments) are correct.

> *"Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure, alors qu'est-ce que c'est ?"*

As you've removed "colloquial" from the question, the construction *"Si ce n'est pas ..., alors qu'est-ce que c'est ?"* is not colloquial. But *"passer un sale quart d'heure"* is.

Note that you can also shorten removing *"alors"*: *"Si ce n'est pas ..., qu'est-ce que c'est ?"*. This can be considered as a lighter way to say it.

More familiar ways, now, as *"si"* has no complement, and the following sentences are usually orally used:

> *"Si ce n'est pas ce qu'on appelle passer un sale quart d'heure !"*
>
> *"Si ce n'est pas ce qu'on appelle passer un sale quart d'heure, ça !"*
>
> *"Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure !"*
>
> *"Si ce n'est pas passer un sale quart d'heure, ça !"*

About "ça":

It can be placed "anywhere"... the point is to highlight (accentuate) it when you speak. That can also be:

> *"Ca, si ce n'est pas... !"*
>
> *"Si ça, ce n'est pas... !"*

For more emphasis, you can use "alors" in another way (still orally):

> *"Alors ça, si ce n'est pas... !"*
>
> *"Alors, si ça... !"

Other aspects:

The first sentence "Si xxx, alors xxx ?" is a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). So, I'm wondering if the various declinations of it need to keep the interrogation point... To tell the truth, I don't know. But I think that orally speaking you can tone it as a question.

Additionally, you can invert the locution. For instance (if X then what is not X?):

> *"si ça c'est un bon match, alors qu'est-ce qu'un mauvais match ?"*

Comment: "interrogation point" se dit _question mark_ ;) et d'après  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Punctuation que vous citez il semble plus prudent de le garder. Je pense qu'un point d'exclamation ne serait toutefois pas choquant.